# How to I tell Eclipse to build using a different version of a package from a different library?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, mobile, package

I'm currently trying to build an android application using the Android 4.1.2 Java libraries.

Unfortunately, I want to use a newer version of the org.json package, which appears in that library.

Am I able to tell Eclipse not to use the org.json package in the Android 4.1.2 Jar?

Comment: @YogendraSingh http://www.json.org/java/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you are encountering a Java package name collision. Unfortunately as the code in Android comes pre-packaged, your best bet is to rename the newer json package and use that to avoid using the prebuilt one.

Answer (score 0):

If same class with package is available through two different JARs in the buildpath, you can't do that properly.

**One step you may try** is to put new jar on top in the `order` using `Order and Export` tab of `Eclipse` build path UI.

The best way is to update you Android Lib folder in the file system and replace the older jar with the newer JAR.

**Please note:** There might be an **compatibility** issue when you attempt to use a different JAR than the one supplied with the package.